# workaround to control nested AMP-Elements on user consent

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I know this is not the right approach how one should implement the AMP-AD Element with embedded Iframe on user Consent policy. 
But suppose there are cases where we are not fully convinced that it works as expected when user decide to  Opt-Out. (This may be vendor specific issue, although it has been said that we can fully relay on its functionality)

Therefore my question is: Is there some posibiblity, even by misusing some other element to disable the AMP-AD Element independent from itself for example by nesting AMP-Elements?

```
<amp-? data-block-on-consent   ....>
   <amp-ad data-block-on-consent type="xyz" ...></amp-ad>
</amp-?>
```